# After with editor the current status is submitted to journal

Tags: elsevier

I have communicated my article to one elsevier journal. After being with editor for more than one month, the current status is "submitted to journal". I am confused regarding this status? What does it signify, kindly answer me?

Comment: I don't think so.@scaaahu

Comment: The linked question is about the workflow under normal circumstance when you submit an article to a journal. Any abnormal case is the question for the journal. You need to ask them. We cannot  guess anything for you.

Comment: I think [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12497/546) would be helpful to you.

Comment: I got the same case, @SibaMishra, can ou tell me what you get after ?

Comment: Reject or out of scope probably. I didn't remember

Answer (score 7):

Based on my experience, the review process in most of Elsevier journals are as,

1. Submitted to journal(Editor tries to find an associate editor or referees for your article)
2. With editor (Editor evaluation step)
3. Under review (Your paper is sent for referees (reviewers))
4. Required reviews completed (Minimum number of reviews for your article received)
5. Editor evaluation or with editor (Editor decision for your paper based on reviewers comments)
6. revised or rejected or recommended for resubmission based on reviews comments

This is the most common process for Elsevier journals. Also, the length of time in each step is totally dependent on the journal and especially on the editor in chief. You can find some info about the review process in the newly added feature in some Elsevier's journals named as journal insight e.g. see this one, [Journal insight](http://journalinsights.elsevier.com/journals/0031-3203)

Comment: what about the status changed to submitted to journal after with editor status??

Comment: @SibaMishra For some journals, as a pre-evaluation step editor holds the paper for a short period of time to decide about the paper. I think that your next step is the review process or you would receive editor evaluation about your paper.

Answer (score 4):

**with editor** does not always mean that the paper with editor. It means that the editorial office has requested one researcher to take care of the submitted paper as editor. It is now the responsibility of that person to *accept or reject* the *request*.

In your case, probably the intended researcher has not accepted the request. So the status comes to 0 again. In few days the editorial office will again send a request to some other researcher to be *editor in charge or handling editor*.

Hope this helps.