# Who( editor or reviewer) reviews a revised manuscript?

Tags: peer-review

I sent an article to a top journal. It was reviewed by 2 reviewers. The decision made was 'revision'. I revised the manuscript and sent a detailed point by point response to reviewer comments. During revision the status changed directly from 'with editor' to 'decision in process' within a span of 4 days. I was under the impression that the reviewers would go through the paper again and based on their comments a decision would be made by the editor. But it seems that the editor is making the decision himself. Is this correct?
. The result is yet to be received, so fingers crossed ;)

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Welcome! From this [question about journal workflow](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/how-much-time-does-each-stage-of-paper-in-elsevier-editorial-system-ees-take), it seems that "Decision in Process" can mean the editor is making the decision OR that it's going back out to reviewers. Good luck!