# Does “under review” status after minor revision always mean the paper has been sent back to reviewers?

Tags: peer-review, elsevier

I have a paper which was invited to be resubmitted after minor revisions. Normally, the editor decides the outcome after this. In this case, however, the status went back to under review after I resubmitted. Does this mean it got sent to reviewers or the editor is evaluating it? Any experience here? It’s an Elsevier journal.

Comment: Not really, does “under review” ever mean the editor is assessing it at an Elsevier journal? Or does it always mean peer reviewers

Comment: This may also help: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/12499/68109

Comment: Interpreting the status reports from a publisher's submission system is, in my opinion, the modern equivalent of reading tea leaves.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

If the paper is not with reviewers, the status should be 'with editor'. If the editor made a decision, it should be 'decision in progress'. If you're seeing 'under review', it's because the paper has been sent to reviewers.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I submitted a revision to an Elsevier Journal and it said under review but the comments I received back strongly implied that only the editor reviewed the revisions and did not send them back to the original reviewers.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth how long was your paper under review for? That could still be explainable as, e.g., the editor invited the reviewers, then decided not to wait (or the reviewer simply submitted no comments).

Comment: Not long, a few weeks. It was a journal with a quick turnaround. It came back for a second minor review (I addressed the reviewers comments but I failed to address those from the editor as I read them as general comments - after addressing those also it was accepted very quickly - less than a week).

Comment: @DavidWaterworth Did you see the "under review" status after addressing the editor's comments, or before? If it's before, it sounds quite plausible - the reviewer did recommend acceptance to the editor, who on examining the paper realized you hadn't addressed their comments.

Comment: I only saw it say under review, but it's plausible it changed between different states without me seeing.