# Consequences of publishing work using text from millions of Sci-Hub articles

Tags: ethics, publishability, machine-learning, sci-hub

I have a project that involves large-scale text embedding of biological literature. In this case, each biology article would be given a set of numbers (embedding) based on the text in the article. We would then analyze these embeddings exclusively.

Ideally I would use full-text articles rather than being limited to abstracts. However, only a small subset of PubMed has full text freely available (PubMed Central). I have found that I can access and torrent millions of full-text PubMed articles through Sci-Hub.

What are the potential implications of using these Sci-Hub articles when it comes to publishing my work? Would this be considered a major red flag by the journal editor (especially from larger, older journals, e.g. Cell, Nature, Science)? Is it even necessary to specify where I got the full-text articles from, barring a peer reviewer requesting it?

Comment: One option would be to do your initial studies with whatever material you can easily obtain, and then negotiate some kind of arrangement with e.g. PubMed for research purposes before the publication.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the articles? How much information from each processed article is retained in the final result?

Comment: Have you considered trying the analysis with just the abstracts? It is likely that, unless your embedding dimension is extremely large, you are going to get similar results with abstract-based embedding. The whole dataset of fulltexts is going to be colossal

Comment: https://twitter.com/sgrodriques/status/1733193844110557432

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is standard practice to detail in the methods of a paper how any large literature review was undertaken. Often people specify the search terms they used and the database they accessed. In your case I don't see how you can avoid specifying the sources of your papers.

Since Sci-Hub exists almost in protest to most major publishers, it is unlikely any of them would publish work based on exploiting it as a resource. If there are independent journals in your field who are taking an ethical stance on publishing then perhaps they would consider it. There are some journals run entirely by academics who are probably much more sympathetic.

Comment: "It is standard practice to detail in the methods of a paper how any large literature review was undertaken. Often people specify the search terms they used and the database they accessed."  Yes, but they don't usually detail whether, having identified papers to include, they read (e.g.) the hardcopy from the library shelf or the online copy from ScienceDirect - surely the choice to use SciHub is in that category.

Comment: -1 since *Since Sci-Hub exists almost in protest to most major publishers, it is unlikely any of them would publish work based on exploiting it as a resource* is not true, there are many pure OA publishers, although I am not sure any of them would publish work based on illegally acquired data.

Comment: @DanielHatton I was thinking more "we used search term X and Y in Scopus which returned 371 results. These are the papers we've used as the basis for our review". As far as I can tell the rough equivalent here would be "we scraped all of biology SciHub to get the papers we review here".

Comment: @thosphor Ah, OK.  I was thinking OP's plan was "we used search term X and Y in Scopus which returned 371 results, then we downloaded those 371 papers from Sci-Hub", but rereading the question, I think your interpretation is more plausible.

Comment: *it is unlikely any of them would publish work based on exploiting it as a resource.* - since the only way the "publishers" are involved in the publishing process is collecting money, they will not even know such a paper has been submitted. The decision to accept is done by voluntary editorial board, which could not care less about publisher's political interests.

Answer (score 7):

You are concerned with the wrong question, namely whether you have to disclose how you obtained these articles.

The question you *should* be asking is whether it is *ethical* and *legal* to use what Sci-Hub offers. Regardless of one's position on the commercial publishing model used in the sciences today, the *legal* answer is that these journals own the copyright to these articles, and that they make them available for a fee to universities and others willing to pay. Sci-Hub do not own the copyright, and violate copyright laws by making articles available for free. It is likely not legal (perhaps depending on the country you're in) to download all of these articles.

So what you propose is to use a data set you cannot legally own when downloaded from Sci-Hub. This is no different from analyzing the painting technique on a Picasso a friend of yours stole: It is certainly not ethical to attempt to publish data obtained from this data set. Whether you can conceal this fact from reviewers should not be your first thought.

Comment: "not ethical" - yes; "no different from stealing" - no; it is different. The word "stealing" does not really suit the situation (I know it is a popular term). The data remain available to other, legally paying users. This type of copyright violation is more like fare evasion. Getting a service without paying for it. The service does not disappear for others, but it gets a tad more expensive. That being said, it is not clear whether the prices charged for many journal articles based on free authorship/editorship/reviews by government-funded scientists should not be called highway robbery.

Comment: My previous comment notwithstanding, you are of course right that OP should ask the ethical question first and foremost.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Fair point. I edited to say that you're publishing on a painting someone else stole. That's still unethical. As for highway robbery: I don't disagree. But that's a separate question. You're not allowed to steal from Elon Musk either, even though he's rich and perhaps unethically so.

Comment: This answer conflates ethical and legal. You separate them at the start and then conclude that because it's illegal it's also unethical. The two often do not overlap. Many would argue that SciHub is the ethical response to an unethical system. Assuming the OP is doing good science, they're even showing how that science wouldn't have been possible within the publishing industry's current boundaries.

Comment: @thosphor I would disagree on the overlap. I cannot think of cases where it is *illegal* to publish something (short of revealing national security secrets). But I can think of many research topics where the data was obtained illegally (say, by infecting people with syphilis) and where publishing the data would be unethical. Today, of course, IRBs would not give you ethical clearance for such experiments, and journals will not publish such papers *because publishing without IRB approval is unethical*.

Comment: As for whether the publishing system is unethical or not: I agree with you that it is not. But I do not think that scientists should mete out vigilante justice.

Comment: Just because something is “illegal”, not necessarily “unethical”. OP may break a contract term, but not all contracts are automatically fair or moral. Also, text analysis and scrapping is kind of forbidden even when one is subscribed to a journal, so the publisher is not missing any fees if someone scrapes SciHub version of papers.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Breaking criminal law may be vigilantism, but breaking civil contract law is not. Also, researchers are enablers and one of the main cause of the deeply flowed publishing system, and it is questionable if following the present practices itself is any more moral behavior.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Of course there are many areas where the law and ethics overlap. But that doesn't mean they are equivalent. There are many areas where they don't overlap. Obviously ethics are up to debate, but I don't think anyone would argue that ethics follow from legality. Your example of national security secrets illustrates my point: whistleblowing laws are necessary to prevent the law being used to suppress ethical behaviour.

Comment: In a country with a highly repressive, punitive and undemocratic system of government, basic research into topics considered forbidden may be illegal. That doesn't make conducting and even publishing such research unethical. The copyright laws in the United States *are* highly repressive, punitive and undemocratic...draw your own conclusions.

Comment: "But I can think of many research topics where the data was obtained illegally (say, by infecting people with syphilis)" Are you under the impression that actually happened?

Comment: Folks, all I'm trying to say is that there is an ethical question to answer that is bigger than the question "Am I going to get caught".

Comment: Maybe a better analogy is "entering a museum without paying the ticket, and analyzing the painting techniques on the Picasso in it".

Comment: This is true. But the "fruit of a poisoned tree" doctrine doesn't necessarily apply here. AI LLM are trained on content not legally available for reproduction, yet courts have ruled that their output is copyright-free, rather than copyright-infringing. If OP's project is similarly transformative, that may apply.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it even necessary to specify where I got the full-text articles from, barring a peer reviewer requesting it?

Authors are generally encouraged to give full details of their work, such that other researchers can duplicate them. So: yes.

> What are the potential implications of using these Sci-Hub articles when it comes to publishing my work?

Opinions on Sci-Hub tend to be very polarizing, and there's a significant number of people who split both ways. Which means that if they ever find out you used Sci-Hub, some large number of people will strongly disapprove.

On the legal side, you might be liable for copyright infringement, although there are so many people using Sci-Hub that it's improbable you yourself will be sued.

> Would this be considered a major red flag by the journal editor (especially from larger, older journals, e.g. Cell, Nature, Science)?

As mentioned, opinions on Sci-Hub tend to be very polarizing. For people who dislike Sci-Hub, this would surely be a major red flag and maybe sufficient for automatic desk rejection.

It's possible you'll hit sympathetic editors all the way and the paper ends up accepted, but it's still possible in this case that the publisher will override the editor and refuse to publish the paper. One might think reputable publishers never do this, but it's empathetically the case that they can and do, e.g.:

- If the authors cannot pay the APC
- [If sanctions prohibit the publisher from publishing the paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/197466/are-there-any-countries-whose-academics-editors-are-prohibited-from-working-with)

Similar legal objections could also apply to your paper (although [this Law.SE question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96096/can-a-journal-legally-publish-research-conducted-on-copyrighted-data) suggests that the journal would be in the legal clear, they might not want to take the risk, even if it is legal).

Comment: "On the legal side, you might be liable for copyright infringement, although there are so many people using Sci-Hub that it's improbable you yourself will be sued." Does that probability remain small even in cases where there exists an admission in writing of very large-scale infringement from a named author?

Comment: @Anyon don't remember where I read it, but I definitely read somewhere that the optics of a publisher suing researchers would look very bad for the publisher, so publishers are unlikely to do it.

Comment: @Allure that sounds like the opinion of a single person. It makes sense but is far from a guarantee. It may not apply so much to a large-scale infringement.

Answer (score 7):

The data collection you describe probably violates copyright laws. The specific legality of downloading articles from SciHub depends on the jurisdiction and on other circumstances; e.g., personal use is legal, but scientific research is not [in Switzerland](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52247/is-it-illegal-in-switzerland-to-download-scientific-books-from-sci-hub), and your proposed scraping of millions of articles will probably rather fall in the latter category. Typically, no publisher will come after you for downloading a few articles, but you are proposing to download *millions* of articles, and then to advertise to the world what you did by publishing an article about it.

First, most publishers will not accept a paper based on questionable-to-illegal data collection. (You might be able to argue that your particular approach was indeed legal in your jurisdiction, but then things become hairy if the jurisdiction of the publisher is also relevant, and nobody really wants to get their legal team involved in the publishing decision.) Commercial publishers won't like it because you are... demonstrating your contempt for their business model. (I toyed with other metaphors.) And even if "nonstandard" publishers might like it, e.g., journals run entirely by open science aficionado academics whose philosophy and ethics this very much resonates with, if they have any sense at all, they will not publish something like your paper, because it opens them up to *serious* litigation. And they know full well that the commercial publishers will absolutely love having an opening like this to put them out of business, and at the same time send a clear message to all the other academics that might consider intruding on their turf.

Because, second, make no mistake: if you plan on doing something this (probably) illegal, *and publishing a paper about it*, then **litigation may well be coming your way**. There have been high profile cases about people breaking copyright in similar ways, and publishers have enough legal experts to drag you through courts for years. (Edit - Franck Dernoncourt asks the obvious follow-up question here: [Has any researcher been sued for using Sci-Hub data in their research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/203778/4140)) And at the same time, your internet service provider will get wind of this and may start litigating as well, because you very probably broke your service agreement in multiple ways. (Did you read all the fine print you accepted?) If you are doing this from a university account, the least that can happen is that your IT department could close your account, then you may be expelled if you are a student, and terminated if you are an employee.

If you write a paper that actually gets published and nobody reads, so the legal s***shorm does not arrive immediately, you are now living with a huge problem on your hands that could explode into your face at absolutely any time in the rest of your life. You do not know whether someone will dig this up in ten years and make your life miserable in the ways described above, even if the legal aspects are under a statute of limitations. You don't know how copyright laws and court decisions will develop in the coming decades, but doing something like this *now* is not a good starting point for the rest of your life.

And all of these may well happen even if you have a case that your method was legal in the first place. If your school expels you over this and you win a case against it in court in five years, then yes, you did win, but was the legal hassle worth it?

Comment: Sometimes civil disobedience is worth the risk.

Comment: Downvote reasons: Your unsupported claim that someone would get sued for this seems unlikely to me. People have publicly done this before; I don't know if they published in journals about it, but they have openly published it on the web and haven't been sued yet. You can find these projects by googling; they're still up. And your boldfaced instruction not to do this is opinion-based, condescending, and not responsive to the question as asked.

Comment: @GlennWillen: thank you for giving your reasons. I stand by my post.

Comment: I have not downvoted you and agree with most of what you say, but the statement at the very beginning ("Downloading articles from SciHub is illegal.") seems problematic. This likely depends on where you are.

Comment: [Has any researcher been sued for using Sci-Hub data in their research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/203778/452)

Comment: @Glenn Willen "People have publicly done this before" People have, under their own name, written scientific papers analyzing millions of SciHub articles? If you don't want to link to them, can you at least tell us what to google for?

Comment: @Nick can you name a jurisdiction where downloading articles from SciHub is not illegal? I'm curious if any exist.

Comment: @Nick [Is downloading articles from SciHub legal in some jurisdictions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/203876/452)

Comment: @Allure [Switzerland](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52247/is-it-illegal-in-switzerland-to-download-scientific-books-from-sci-hub), for instance.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni curiously, I remembered that question, and interpreted the answer as saying it is illegal, in particular: "Downloading a book or article from Sci-hub for scientific research is illegal".

Comment: @Allure And, a few lines above: "Downloading a book for personal use is legal", irrespective of the source. That answer makes many distinctions and subtle points; one of them is "for scientific research" vs. "for private use". In particular, though, the blanket statement in this answer "Downloading articles from SciHub is illegal" is false.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Presumably we are interpreting the context differently. In the other perspective, the OP is not downloading articles for personal use; he/she is downloading papers for scientific research.

Comment: It would help to add qualifiers then, so that the ambiguity is resolved; for instance "downloading articles from Sci-Hub is illegal *in some cases*."

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: after the ongoing discussion, I have toned down my answer. I would still argue strongly against this whole idea, but you are right that the legal aspects are less clear-cut than I thought originally.

Answer (score 4):

> What are the potential implications of using these Sci-Hub articles when it comes to publishing my work?

The most important implication is that you are contributing to science by using one of the best datasets for scientific text mining. While this may cause the paper to be rejected by many venues, the goal of a researcher is to contribute to scientific progress. You can still upload the paper to arXiv or similar venues.

> Is it even necessary to specify where I got the full-text articles from, barring a peer reviewer requesting it?

No. What matters is describing the dataset. The way you obtained doesn't have to be disclosed if you think this may cause issues.

When you publish your article, please consider [thanking Alexandra Elbakyan](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22thank+alexandra+elbakyan%22) in the acknowledgement section, as [Nemo](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/32575/nemo) [reports](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87688/what-are-the-onsequences-of-using-sci-hub?rq=1#comment339557_87716) it is increasingly common.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers seem to assume that you don't have any legal access to the papers and your only motive for using sh is to acquire them. This baffles me: if you have a university affiliation, you most likely have access to most of all of them through your uni library.
So while I'm not an expert in law, I don't think technically you're stealing something you already have access to and your library has paid for. The premise of stealing is that you are using something without paying that you should have/would have and the seller loses money because of this. But in your case it's already paid for by your employer (university). Unless you are unemployed and without access to a library that offers the papers. In such a case it is baffling to consider using sci hub *unethical* but maybe that's just me...
By the way, the usual practice in such cases or cases of lack of access is to email the authors and ask for the paper. Is that unethical? Who here hasn't done it? Everyone I've known has been on both ends of these emails. We're then all criminals and bad people for not telling our colleagues to spend the 40bucks and buy the article from the publisher, of which we as authors get of course 0 royalty because we (and the reviewers) donated our labor to benefit multi billion corporations lol.

Anyway, in the end you have simply chosen to access the information you anyway have access to in a way that's more convenient to you. There's no material loss to the publisher.
I guess alternatively you could ask your library to do that for you and prepare/deliver you a package of the papers you need.

Nor should reporting some consolidated data based on an idiosyncratic numeric ratings of these papers be illegal. If that doesn't fly then how do systematic reviews, which disclose much more data from the individual studies?!?

Finally, I've never heard of a requirement to disclose how you accessed the papers you used. This sounds even more baffling than the rest. Do I have to say "these 20 were OA, these 10 were preprints, these 5 were through interlibrary loan, these 30 were through the library and these 10 I emailed the authors". I've never seen a paper reporting such info but who knows maybe it's different in biology!?! Are you then supposed to attach also the library receipt and the emails from colleagues as evidence?

On a final note, sounds like preparing the bibliography for your paper is going to be a pain in the derriere  that alone would make the feasibility of the study questionable

Comment: "So while I'm not an expert in law, I don't think technically you're stealing something you already have access to and your library has paid for" Incorrect. ToS may prevent anything beyond regular reading. There are special licenses for text mining e.g. see the Elsevier Text and Data Mining (TDM) License. "On a final note, sounds like preparing the bibliography for your paper is going to be a pain in the derriere": you have no idea what OP meant by embeddings and/or are unfamiliar with AI publications.

Answer (score 0):

If your search terms are for the articles on pubmed, how you got the full text doesn't matter at all. All that matters is how you found the articles with your search terms with respect to what you would report. No need to mention sci-hub as such in this context.