# Has any researcher been sued for using Sci-Hub data in their research?

Tags: legal-issues, sci-hub

I read on [Consequences of publishing work using text from millions of Sci-Hub articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/203751/452):

> make no mistake: if you plan on doing something this blatantly illegal, and publishing a paper about it, then litigation is coming your way. There have been high profile cases about people breaking copyright in similar ways, and publishers have enough legal experts to drag you through courts for years. [Stephan Kolassa](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/4140/stephan-kolassa)

Has any researcher been sued for using Sci-Hub data in their research? Assume we are talking about paywalled articles that the Sci-Hub dataset makes available for free.

By using Sci-Hub data in their research I mean using a significant  numbers (let's say millions) of articles for research purpose such as  text mining or training word embeddings, not just downloading a few articles (the latter is addressed in this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87688/452)).

Comment: Is it even possible to download millions of articles from Sci-Hub? I assume the website will be rate-limited. They pay for bandwidth, too.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The OP of the [linked question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/203738/17254) mentions having found a torrent option to download the articles, which wouldn't be subject to (traditional) rate limiting, only the availability of peers seeding the data. [Related OpenData thread](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7084).

Comment: Perhaps related ... I see that a group of authors is suing some AI companies for using the authors' copyrighted texts to train an AI.

Comment: The sci-hub project has long used multiple mirror website as had the sci-hub affiliate project, LibraryGenesis. Both projects also make their database indexes and database contents available for `torrent` access. When I last looked at the Library Genesis metadata, it seemed that the entire library (including multiple duplicates) exceeded 100 terabytes. The list of unique Sci-Hub DOIs exceeds 2 gigabytes.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is surprisingly difficult to answer. Why? Because of what it means, in different jurisdictions, to "sue" someone. If, for example, a researcher were to download articles from Sci Hub and were later to receive a threat of legal action from a publisher, it is likely that the matter would be settled, not only "out-of-court", but without a writ ever being issued  (or, in the United States, a complaint being filed and a summons issued) . Even were a writ to be issued, there are many jurisdictions in which such writs are difficult to find or search.  Taken together, these possibilities probably put a lot of potentially relevant information beyond reach.

Despite those limitations, I took the step of looking at the website of the World Legal Information Institute ([WorldLII](http://www.worldlii.org/)) and searched for both ***scihub*** and ***sci-hub*** (hyphenated) and found no instances of any case in which a researcher was being sued. Likewise I searched each of the affiliated websites listed at the end of the WorldLII website (including [AustLII](http://www.austlii.edu.au/), [CanLII](http://www.canlii.org/), etc) and found no relevant case. I did not search for cases in the world's most litigious country because I could find no free-access database. On the other hand, I was amused to find a New Zealand tribunal case involving a chiropractor in which a a direct link is given to an article on Sci Hub.

Answer (score 1):

There don't appear to be any instances in which researchers have been sued for using Sci-Hub data in such a manner. I suspect this is not because publishers are uninterested in suing researchers who do this, but because most researchers are going to avoid admitting to using Sci-Hub data in that manner, especially when they can pre-train on one of the general text corpora and then fine-tune on all articles from PubMed for domain specificity - legally.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is very difficult (or perhaps impossible?) to track individuals and determine whether they are using Sci-Hub. I think even your institution may not interfere with your data traffic unless public authorities request it. I am unsure if, for a researcher outside the U.S., any court could make such a decision.

Sometimes, when you download an article, it provides some data about the server that Sci-Hub uses for the download. If a researcher publicly uses a downloaded article, and if it's possible to prove that this article was obtained through Sci-Hub using the provided information, that person might face consequences. In the end, I think collecting evidence on this would be quite challenging, and it could turn out to be costly for those looking to take legal action against researchers using Sci-Hub.