# Is downloading articles from SciHub legal in some jurisdictions?

Tags: legal-issues, sci-hub

I read this comment:

> The statement at the very beginning ("Downloading articles from SciHub is illegal.") seems problematic. This likely depends on where you are. [Nick](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/169282/nick) [2 days ago](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/203738/consequences-of-publishing-work-using-text-from-millions-of-sci-hub-articles/203751#comment549191_203751)

This makes me wonder: is downloading articles from SciHub legal in some jurisdictions?

Assume that we are referring to paywalled articles that are not in the public domain or under some permissive license.

Comment: This might make more sense at Law.SE, together with some information for non-academics about what SciHub is. Then again, I don't know whether "is X legal in some jusrisdictions" is well received there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention lists the countries that are not signatories.

Comment: "Sin is geographical." (Bertrand Russel)

Comment: @Michael_1812 I disagree, putting scientific research behind paywalled is a sin any location.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  Touché :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't read the original language to confirm, but it's possible that the bill [discussed here](https://torrentfreak.com/belarus-legalizes-piracy-of-movies-music-software-of-unfriendly-nations-230109/) also legalizes downloading scientific articles in **Belarus**.

The bill, passed in January 2023, is named "On the limitation of exclusive rights to objects of intellectual property"; allegedly it makes it legal to commit piracy against IP held by actors in foreign "unfriendly nations".

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be legal in [Switzerland](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52247/is-it-illegal-in-switzerland-to-download-scientific-books-from-sci-hub), for instance. I asked the same question in the past, after a similar thread.